# How to determine $E(X(XZ))$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence

The question in the book was:

Give an example of a pair of dependent and joinlty continuous random variables $X,Y$ for which $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

Example given: Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent. $X$ has normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$. $Z$ takes the value $1$ or $-1$ with probability $1/2$. Now define $Y=XZ$.

**My question:**

So we know that $E(Z)=0$, so $E(XZ)=0$. But how can I see that $E(XY)$ (so in this case $E(X(XZ))$ is $0$? $X$ and $XZ$ are dependent so I cant split them into $E(X)E(XZ)$ and say that that implies that $E(X(XZ))$ is $0$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $X(XZ)=X^2Z$ and $X^2$ is independent of $Z$ because $X$ is independent of $Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathsf E(X^2Z)=\mathsf E(X^2)~\mathsf E(Z)$ due to the independency of $X^2$ and $Z$.